# Ruby view nested element inside index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models with the following relationship

```
Event
  has_many :comments
Comment
  belongs_to :event
```

What I would like to do is in Post.index is to show elements of Post but also comment.descriptions.

Here a controller

```
def index
  @events = Event.all(:include => :comments)
  ...
```

Here how its build

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
  @event.comments.build
end
```

But i am not to sure how to show in post.index.html comments.description. I try this but it fails

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% if event.comments.count <= 1 %>
    <%= event.description%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The error is undefined method (description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop through the comments for each event while you are looping through the events.

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% event.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, though just going through the relationship it would save coding, will mark has answer has soon has i can